# Can a finite group of even order exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Wouldn't that imply that there are two identity elements in our group?

Comment: A quick counter example are dihedral groups

Comment: The cyclic group of order $2$, for example (there are cyclic groups of all orders).  Why would you think this was impossible?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has only two elements

Answer (score 2):

There are examples here that show your conjecture is incorrect. This is why I think you're confused:

If a group has even order than it has a subgroup of order a power of $2$. Every element of that subgroup will have even order, so there will be elements $g$ other than the identity $e$ such that $g^2 = e$. Perhaps you thought that the identity was the only element that could be its own inverse.

Answer (score 0):

The order of a group is just the number of elements, so you can take the integers modulo any even number under addition.  This is the cyclic group.  Like all groups, it has just one identity element.  Why do you think there should be two?  The Klein group has four elements and every one is its own inverse.